# Can you pass params for associated model on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

What i want to do - 
I've got 2 models `Record` and `Author`. when calling `Record.create params` i whant to pass params for associated Author model. 
`Record` has column `body` and `Author` has column `name` 
When i try to pass as follows
`Record.create { body: "some text", author: { name: 'Some name'}}`
i get error `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: author`

How can i do what i need ?

**UPDATE 1**
association - Record has author

Comment: Are the two models associated?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. forgot to mention this!

Comment: No problem - I'll write an answer for you now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nested Attributes**

You'll probably be looking for [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), or [`inverse_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Setting+Inverses) - both relying on an association between your two models:

```
#app/models/record.rb
Class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :author
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :author
end

#app/models/author.rb
Class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :record
end
```

Essentially, you'll need to **build** the associative data, allowing you to send the associated attributes through to your other model. I'll explain this further down the page

This is what I would do if I were you:

```
#app/controllers/records_controller.rb
Class RecordsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @record = Record.new
      @record.author.build
   end

   def create
      @record = Record.new record_params
      @record.save
   end

   private

   def record_params
      params.require(:record).permit(:record, :attributes, author_attributes: [:name])
   end
end

#app/views/records/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @record do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :record %>
   <%= f.fields_for :author do |a| %>
      <%= a.text_field :name %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to save the `author` params / attributes upon save

--

**inverse**

Inverse attributes are also another idea for you.

I'm not sure whether they'll work directly in this instance, but you *could* use the following:

```
#app/models/record.rb
Class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :author, inverse_of: :author
   before_create :build_record
end

#app/models/author.rb
Class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :record, inverse_of: :record
   before_create :set_options

   private

   def set_options
      self.draft = true unless self.record.draft.present?
   end
end
```

This means you *should* be able to access the nested attribute data (I'm not sure whether you have to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` still in this instance) in your other model

---

**ActiveRecord Objects**

Finally, you need to consider the role of `ActiveRecord objects` in this setup

Please remember you're not just passing single items of data here - you're constructing & passing *objects*. This means you have to consider how they work & what they mean. I'll give you a brief explanation:

Rails, because its built on Ruby, is an [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) framework. This means that every piece of data you create / use in this is an *object*. Objects are much different than variables - they are deeper & have much more data contained within them, allowing them to be used in a variety of different ways:

[image]

Rails makes use of objects in many different ways; the main one being that a lot of the helpers & other methods build themselves *around* the objects. That's why you get the `resources` directive in your routes, and can do the following: `<%= link_to @user.name, @user %>`

The problem many people have is they don't understand the value of object-orientation in a Rails app, and consequently try and think about their logic from the perspective of a disjointed system. Conversely, and this will help you tremendously, you need to consider that every time you create a record, you're building an *object*, and consequently, you need to ensure you build your app around them.

As noted, you have to ensure you have an association between the objects you wish to create. If you do that, you'll be able to build them both at the same time

Comment: to build the nested association, change `@record.author.build` by: `@record.author_build`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this hopefully will solve your problem:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :author
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :author, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

And for more details see [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)